# Share updated variable with factory (variable scope)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to share an updated variable (updated from a function) through a factory (Angularjs)

I have the following factory:

```
appTspSrv.factory('shared', function(db) {

    var entities;

    var getEntities = function(){
        db.query('getEntities', function(err, doc) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                entities = doc.rows;
            }
        });
    };
    getEntities();

    return {
        getEntities: function() {
            return entities;
        }
    }

});
```

When I call my factory's function from the controller I get 'undifined':

```
console.log(shared.getEntities());
```

Why is that and how can I fix this?

Comment: I assume that db.query is async and you're calling `shared.getEntities` before it's had a chance to return and update `entities`.

Comment: @DylanWatt shared.getEntities is async and no I call it after I updated entities... The weird behavior is that if I set entities to something when I declare it then getEntities will return that value. To make sure getEntities(); works, I've put a console.log() when I set entities = doc.rows; and got it before calling the shared function!

Comment: It is like if they were two separated variables... One inside the function and the other one outside! Please note that when I print entities when I get it with my async function, it is the right one (I also tried applying $apply on the async without success...)

Comment: @ncohen can you provide plunker?

Comment: @ncohen, anyway, if you get _undefined_ when call `console.log(shared.getEntities());` then `entities` not updated.

Comment: @Grundy I know... It seems that it's only the local variable that gets updated. I'm writing the plunker

Comment: @ncohen check what is `this` in the db handler.

Comment: @Dinesh this is undefined...

Comment: I can't replicate in a plunker... my db is local and I can't really replicate that. It seems that it's because this is undefined in var getEntities = function() . Any solution?

Comment: @ncohen can you provide your _db_? possibly we can emulate it? is it ajax request? or something else?

Comment: @ncohen, can you provide code, where you call `console.log(shared.getEntities());`?

Comment: @ncohen also, you not use _this_ inside your functions, so not matter that it _undefined_

Comment: @Grundy Ok I tried to reproduce it without success...I'm going crazy! In this example, it's working: http://plnkr.co/edit/iD4oawj3RkjKtco2bOOM?p=preview  I tried many things in my app. For example if I call the function var getEntities right after creating it, it works. In addition the variable is defined everywhere except in the return where getEntities: function() is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77935/discussion-between-grundy-and-ncohen).